# "if not a in b" or "if a not in b", which is better, or more pythonic?

Tags: python, conventions

Not sure if this question is trivial, but I'd like to know, is there some culture/convention saying one is better than the other? Or is there some hazard using one of them?

Comment: `if a not in b`, it improves readability :)

Comment: @BrenBarn wow thx~ just don't know how to search it